# If I enable ufw, and disable ssh. Is my base install Ubuntu 12.04 safe from the outside world?

Tags: 12.04, security, ufw

I installed Ubuntu 12.04

I then installed Gufw, enabled it and Set every known application setting to "Deny".

I never installed sshdaemon so I think its off.

My machine still responds to pings... but otherwise is it safe now?

Comment: What do you use the machine for?  Making a local fileserver safe, making a webserver safe and making a desktop computer safe are all very different topics--especially since the most dangerous component of the latter setup is the human operating it.

Answer (score 1):

You are "safe" a clean Ubuntu installation doesn't have any daemons listening by default.

What you need to do is define safe

Answer (score 1):

You can also find out which ports are still open with nmap scanner:

`sudo nmap 127.0.0.1 -p1-65535`

where `127.0.0.1` is your **external** IP (with this specific command you will scan localhost)

and `1-65535` ports range to scan. IIRC by default it scans only something about 1000 ports.